# How to ARIA markup radio buttons used for presentation?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have radio buttons that are used for presentation, not actual form elements:

CSS

```
input[type='radio']:checked + a {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" role="presentation" name="suggestion" id="suggestions_arts centre" value="arts centre" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="search.json?query=arts centre" tabindex="0"><span class="show-for-sr">Search for: </span><span style="font-weight: bold;">arts</span> centre</a>
    <input type="radio" role="presentation" name="suggestion" id="suggestions_arts" value="arts" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="search.json?query=arts" tabindex="0"><span class="show-for-sr">Search for: </span><span style="font-weight: bold;">arts</span></a>
    ...
```

This lets me allow the user to user arrow keys to cycle through links which is what I want. I know this isn't exactly what radio buttons are intended for but neither are  lists intended for navigation, but it's pretty much everywhere now, and it saves having to overcomplicate the page with JavaScript if I can lend some of the browsers built in behaviour.

Anyway, how can I use ARIA to markup the radio/links so that it is clear to screen readers what the purpose of these is for as my chrome plugin (SiteImprove) is telling me - "Input field is missing a description" still, or is what I have above OK?

Answer (score 4):

That's a totally unintuitive behaviour.

Second rule of ARIA:

> Do not change native semantics, unless you really have to.

Fourth rule of ARIA:

> Do not use role="presentation" or aria-hidden="true" on a visible focusable element .

Comment: Yes, exactly. "This lets me allow the user to user arrow keys to cycle through links which is what I want." This is completely unexpected behaviour for links; also they don't need a tabindex attribute since they are focusable by default.